# Typescript conditional types not working with different return types

Tags: typescript

I want to return a different type based on a generic value. For example:

```
interface Base {
  key: string[];
}

class Test<T> {
  value = [];

  getSomething(): (T extends Base ? string[] : string) {
    if (Array.isArray(this.value)) {
      return ['a'] as string[];
    }

    return 'nothing' as string;
  }
}

const v = new Test<Base>().getSomething();
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Type string[] is not assignable to type T extends Base ? string[] :
>   string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional types that still have unresolved (such as `T` inside the function) type parameters in them are generally not assignable from another type (without type assertions). Typescript will not be able to follow the logic in your function to determine that the assignments are safe.

The safest option is to use separate implementation and public signatures:

```
interface Base {
  key: string[];
}

class Test<T> {
  value = [];

  getSomething(): (T extends Base ? string[] : string)
  getSomething(): string[] | string {
    if (Array.isArray(this.value)) {
      return ['a'] as string[];
    }

    return 'nothing' as string;
  }
}

const v = new Test<Base>().getSomething();
```

Or a type assertion (although that works better if you alias the type first)

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to decide return type like this.

Alternative is to return string[] always and return single value in array when class is not inherited from Base.